# How can I speed the download of symbol files from the microsoft (and other) servers?

Tags: download, windbg

My WinDbg is configured to download symbol files from the MS server automatically. When this happens, the process is painful, because it takes time to download the pdb files, which tend to be big. It also so happens that these downloads are not optimized - each download proceeds in a single session. This is unlike what would have happened if I was downloading them manually using some download manager.

So, my question is how can I make these downloads to proceed in several sessions to speed up the process? Needless to say, I prefer free solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: They should get cached locally to disk. If you set your sympath to something like `srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`.

Comment: They are indeed cached. But I am debugging now another product with yet unseen modules, so they are downloaded from the internet and I have a feeling that the hell will freeze over sooner that these downloads end.

Comment: I have no problems with downvoting, but I'll be glad to know the reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the corresponding symbol package for your OS from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx

This will allow you to have a large symbol cache out of the gate.

- Jason

Comment: OK, I have installed the package. As expected, it only contains the symbols for the OS itself. If you have to debug Office or Visual Studio itself (like I had to) then you are out of luck.